# AWS CodePipeline not available for specific Build source

Tags: aws-codepipeline, aws-codebuild

I'm trying to add a 2nd build, based on an existing pipeline. But apparently a few things I don't fully understand.

In the new pipeline, I'm building 2 containers using 2 different repos. In the existing build (FlaskServerBuild) I have for a source:

[image]
[image]

In the existing pipeline that uses that build (FlaskServerPipeline), I see that under the BUILD action I have selected:

[image]

Which is why (I think) am allowed to choose under the Source for that build as AWS CodePipeline. E.g. there's a pipeline that specifies that build.

So I'm trying to create another build project. However for some reason I can't specify the same source, the choices I have are:

[image]

Under my Pipeline's BUILD actions, I HAVE specified the build:

[image]

But still, for some reason I cannot select the AWS CodePipeline as the source. What am I missing for that option to appear? Some connection missing?

Answer (score 1):

Multiple repo sources can be configured in a CodePipeline Pipeline as separate `Source Actions` in the `Source` stage.

The console create-pipeline workflow only allows a single Source Action.  But you can add a second repo as a pipeline source *after* the pipeline is created.

Edit the pipeline to add a second source action: `(Sidebar) [Pipelines > Pipeline] > (Select Pipeline) > ['Edit' Button] > ('Edit: Source' section) ['Edit stage' Button] > ['Add action' Button]`.  Then select a `Source Action` from the `Action Provider` dropdown.

Comment: Okay, I'm missing something else apparently. I just create a brand new pipeline, with just a single build and a single source. However, I still don't have AWS CodePipeline as an available source for my build. Any7 clues?

Comment: @logicOnAbstractions You must create the Build Project for your 2nd source ("Source2") _using the CodePipeline Edit Pipeline interface_, not the CodeBuild add project interface.  Once you have added the new source (see my answer), edit the Pipeline's Build stage.  Add Action with CodeBuild Action Provider.  Set its input artifacts to the Source2's output artifact.  Select the `Create project` button and follow the workflow.  Finish the action setup.